# Mapping degree of $\mathbb{CP}^n\to \mathbb{CP}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Prove that a number $d\in\mathbb Z$ can be realized as the mapping degree deg($f$) of a map $f: \mathbb {CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ if and only if $d$ is of the form $k^n$, with $k\in\mathbb Z$. Hint: use homogeneous coordinates to write down suitable maps.

Attempt: Since $\mathbb{CP}^n=e^0\cup e^2\cup\cdots\cup e^{2n}$, a self-map of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ induces self-maps on these $(n+1)$ cells. Suppose $e^2\to e^2$ has degree $k$, then deg$(f)=\text{deg}(e^n\to e^n)=k^n$, considering the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. Conversely, if we know the degree is $k^n$, we can let the self-map of $e^2$ be $k$.

I don't know if the basic idea in the above argument is correct, even so, I don't know how to make it rigorously, so I hope someone can tell me how to use homogeneous coordinates to do this problem.

Comment: Note that the map f must carry a generator g of the 2nd cohomology group of CP^n to some element of H^2(CP^n; Z)  =  Z, and that g^n generates H^2n(CP^n; Z)  =  Z.

Comment: $f^{*}$ is a ring homomorphism. And use properties of ring homomorphisms